# Add new section on magento admin

Tags: magento

I am struggle with create new `section` under magento `admin->System->configuration->General` tab. I have posted my code here. I don't know where I make mistake. Please help me...

Step 1: app/code/community/Acs/Msureitinfo/etc/config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Acs_Msureitinfo>
            <version>1.6.0.0.0</version>
        </Acs_Msureitinfo>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <frontend>
            <routers>
                 <msureitinfo>
                     <use>standard</use>
                     <args>
                        <module>Acs_Msureitinfo</module>
                        <frontName>msureitinfo</frontName>
                    </args>
                </msureitinfo>
            </routers>
        </frontend>
    </global>
</config>
```

step2: app/code/community/Acs/Msureitinfo/etc/system.xml file

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <msureitinfo translate="label" module="msureitinfo">
           <label>Acs Msureit Configuration</label>
            <tab>general</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>  
            <groups>
                <msureitinfo translate="label">
                    <label>Admin Information</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>101</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                         <keys translate="label comment">
                            <label>Key</label>
                            <comment>Enter your key value</comment>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                             <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </keys>
            </fields>
                </msureitinfo>
            </groups>
        </msureitinfo>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Step 3: app/code/community/Acs/Msureitinfo/etc/adminhtml.xml

```
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <msureitinfo translate="title" module="msureitinfo">
                                        <title>Msureit info section</title>
                                    </msureitinfo>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `Step 1: app/code/community/Acs/Msureitinfo/etc/config.xml file` to the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Acs_Msureitinfo>
            <version>1.6.0.0.0</version>
        </Acs_Msureitinfo>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <frontend>
            <routers>
                 <msureitinfo>
                     <use>standard</use>
                     <args>
                        <module>Acs_Msureitinfo</module>
                        <frontName>msureitinfo</frontName>
                    </args>
                </msureitinfo>
            </routers>
        </frontend>
        <helpers>
            <msureitinfo>
                <class>Acs_Msureitinfo_Helper</class>
            </msureitinfo>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Under **app\code\community\Acs\Msureitinfo** create folder with name **Helper** and add file **Data.php** with the following code

```
<?php

class Acs_Msureitinfo_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have already created helper class but I forgot to add into config.xml file. It works!.